# Sorting Divs Contents With Letter Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs that include a name. I would like to sort the divs based on name and based on the letter the user selects. For example, if the user selects the letter "d", I would like for all divs that include a name that starts with the letter "d" to show up and all other divs be hidden.

Right now, no divs are showing up when I select a letter.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="alphabetical-search">
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>e</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="staff-directory-wrapper">
    <div class="single-staff">
        <div class="name">
            Mark
        </div>
        <div class="position">
            position
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="single-staff">
        <div class="name">
            Sam bob
        </div>
        <div class="position">
            position
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="single-staff">
        <div class="name">
            Charles mark
        </div>
        <div class="position">
            position
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="single-staff">
        <div class="name">
            Rick sam
        </div>
        <div class="position">
            position
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="single-staff">
        <div class="name">
            Joe frank
        </div>
        <div class="position">
            position
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="single-staff">
        <div class="name">
            Bob mark
        </div>
        <div class="position">
            position
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
var alphabets = $('.alphabetical-search ul > li');
var singleStff = $('#staff-directory-wrapper .single-staff');

alphabets.click(function () {
    var letter = $(this), text = $(this).text(), count = 0;

    alphabets.removeClass("active");
    letter.addClass("active");

    singleStff.hide();
    singleStff.each(function (i) {
        var staffName = $(this).find('.name').text();
        if ( text == $(staffName.charAt(0)) ) {
            count += 1;
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe jQuery-Datatables are an option for you? https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues

1. You need to normalize case. The names start with caps, the list letters  don't
2. Need to trim whitespace from the names text
3. `if()` needs to compare the staffname text, not a jQuery object

---

```
alphabets.click(function () {
    var letter = $(this), text = $(this).text().toLowerCase(), count = 0;

    alphabets.removeClass("active");
    letter.addClass("active");

    singleStff.hide();
    singleStff.each(function (i) {
        var staffName = $(this).find('.name').text().trim().toLowerCase();

        if ( text == staffName.charAt(0) ) {
            count += 1;
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xbypjao9/)**</kbd>